# Microsoft Remote Desktop Services - Android

Tags: remote-desktop-services, remoteapp, windows-server-2012-r2

We have recently started testing Remote Desktop Services.  We have deployed the environment using the latest server, Windows Server 2012 R2.  We have deployed the Web Access Roles, RD Gateway, Connection Broker Virtualization Host and Session Host.  We are running both, Virtual machine-based and Session-based deployments.  All of these are working as expected internally and externally when using a Windows workstation as the RDS client, however, the Android client is unable to launch applications.

Once you install the app from Google Play you are given a screen to add Remote Resources.  After entering the appropriate URL, username and password we see the applications that have been published.  Unfortunately, when we attempt to launch an app we get the following error:

*Connection Error*

*Host not found.  Please provide the fully-qualified name or the IP address of the host.*

We have already entered this information otherwise I don't believe we would be able to see the published applications.  I think the error is related to the certificate and how it is being used to connect to the applications.  Since this is in our lab environment we have not configured a valid external certificate on the servers and the trusted certificate that is installed on the android tablet points to our internal server / domain name.

What I would like to know:

Has anyone configured RDS Web Access on Server 2012 R2 and attempted to externally connect an Android or iOS device using the Microsoft supported Remote Desktop client.

Are others experiencing the same problem we are?

Were you able to resolve the issue?
Was it related to the external cert / host name?

Answer (score -1):

I am getting similar issues and here is what I think:

With Server 2008 R2 ,  you could set the Internet Facing IP as the Remote Session Host (rather than the internal server name which is not being resolved from the internet), but this feature seems to be gone in 2012 R2...